# Is it always true that $E[E[X|Y]^2] = E[X|Y]^2$?

Tags: self-study, expected-value, conditional-expectation

X and Y are random variables. So $E[X|Y]$ is conditioned on a random variable.

Do we always have:
   $$E[E[X|Y]^2] = E[X|Y]^2.$$

I have the doubt because I know that $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable and not a number in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The duplicate was originally closed with a link to a thread that has detailed answers to this question. There is no need to keep asking it: if you wish to pursue these ideas, then please edit your original question in response to the suggestions offered in comments there.

Comment: @whuber Ok I will go back to the other closed question, I forgot the exponent in this question.